# Specify wheter ParitionKey or RowKey is wrong when querying Azure Table Storage with invalid values

Tags: c#, repository, azure-table-storage

I have method in my repository to get data from Azure Table Storage.

```
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<T>(partitionKey, rowKey);
TableResult result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);
return result.Result as T;
```

If any of arguments doesn't exist result does not containt any information about it.

The question is - is it possible to determine wheter client provided wrong Partition Key or Row Key without extra querying database? Due the my database structure I should inform the API consumer which of the values is not valid.

EDIT: The only thing that comes to my mind, is to create separate table which stores all the partition key and query this table before executing proper query, but this would result in executing extra queries which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to determine whether client provided wrong Partition Key or Row Key without extra querying database?

As far as I know, there are no built-in methods in Azure storage SDK or operations in [Table service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/table-service-rest-api) that can be used to check whether Partition Key or Row Key that client provided is valid.

You can try to write your own validation method in your program to check whether the given value of Partition Key or Row Key is valid (*check if Partition Key or Row Key value contains any characters that are disallowed in Key Fields, and check if the Key Fields’ value is less than 1kb in size*). And you can check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model#tables-entities-and-properties) to get detailed information about “**characters Disallowed in Key Fields**” and “**supported property types**”.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like below to detect if partition key or row key contains invalid /not allowed chars:

```
public static readonly Regex DisallowedCharsInTableKeys = new Regex(@"[\\\\#%+/?\u0000-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]");
```

Detection of Invalid Table Partition and Row Keys:

```
bool invalidKey = DisallowedCharsInTableKeys.IsMatch(tableKey);
```

If `invalidKey` is true then you can return to the client a proper response before even sending the query to table storage.